# JavaFx 2 buttons 2 Listner 1 result

Tags: button, javafx, listener

My small Application contains 2 buttons each of them have a `addActionListener` entrance and doing other stuffs but which listener is used? 
The one I later add to the pan that event handler will be used but why?

here are some snippents of my code:

```
public class LoginStarter extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    TextField usernameField = new TextField();
    usernameField.setLayoutX(426);
    usernameField.setLayoutY(230);
    usernameField.setPromptText("Username");
    usernameField.setMinSize(148, 24);
    usernameField.setMaxSize(148, 24);
    PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
    passwordField.setLayoutX(426);
    passwordField.setLayoutY(260);
    passwordField.setMinSize(148, 24);
    passwordField.setMaxSize(148, 24);
    passwordField.setPromptText("Password");
    Pane gp = new Pane();
    gp.getChildren().add(minimiseBtn());
    gp.getChildren().add(xBtn());
    gp.getChildren().add(usernameField);
    gp.getChildren().add(passwordField);
    gp.setId("pane");

    Scene scene = new Scene(gp, 1000, 550);
    scene.getStylesheets().addAll(
            this.getClass().getResource("gui.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Corp Commander v0.0.1");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public Button minimiseBtn() {

    Button minimiseBtn = new Button();
    minimiseBtn.setText("");
    minimiseBtn.setMaxSize(20, 20);
    minimiseBtn.setMinSize(20, 20);
    minimiseBtn.setId("minimiseBtn");
    minimiseBtn.setLayoutX(956);
    minimiseBtn.setLayoutY(2);
    minimiseBtn.setOnAction(minimiseBtnListener());

    return minimiseBtn;

}

private EventHandler<ActionEvent> minimiseBtnListener() {
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> eh = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("minimise");

        }
    };
    return eh;
}
public Button xBtn() {
    Button xBtn = new Button();
    xBtn.setText("");
    xBtn.setMaxSize(20, 20);
    xBtn.setMinSize(20, 20);
    xBtn.setId("xBtn");
    xBtn.setLayoutX(978);
    xBtn.setLayoutY(2);

    xBtn.setOnAction(xbtnListener());

    return xBtn;
}

private EventHandler<ActionEvent> xbtnListener() {
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> eh = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("exit");
            System.exit(0);

        }
    };
    return eh;
}
}
```

this CSS is used to :

```
 @CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
 #pane{
-fx-background-image: url("background_image.jpg");
-fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
-fx-background-size: 1000 550;
-fx-background-position: center center;
-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 30, 0.5, 0, 0); 
 opacity: 0.95;
}

#xBtn{
-fx-background-image: url("exitBtn2.png");
-fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
-fx-background-size: 20 20;
-fx-background-position: center center;
-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 30, 0.5, 0, 0);
-fx-background-color: transparent;
}

#minimiseBtn{
-fx-background-image: url("minusBtn2.png");
-fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
-fx-background-size: 20 20;
-fx-background-position: center center;
-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 30, 0.5, 0, 0);
-fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. The application seems to work as expected when I run it. Can you explain what you application is doing that is different from what you expect?

Comment: i have 2 buttons and they do the same this is my problem they uses the event handler that will aded later  so if i first add the xbuton and then the minimisebutton then the minimise handler will be used from both and i dont understand why ?

Comment: When you press a button, the handler attached to that button is invoked. It doesn't matter what order they are added to the pane. I tried switching the order of `add(xBtn())` and `add(minimiseBtn())` and it still behaved as expected. (I may be misunderstanding your question. It would help if you could write clearly, in sentences, with punctuation, so that others can understand what you are saying.)

Comment: you understand me Right. but i hav exact this problem!
i now have deatatched the lister from one button and the button still doing thomething if i hit him. i dont know what is hapen!?

Comment: Can you show the relevant code? If I comment out either of the `setOnAction(...)` methods, that button no longer invokes any listener methods, as expected. I can't reproduce the issue.